Lebesgue integrability wrt to a measure space and its completion

Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space and $(X, \overline{\Sigma}, \overline{\mu})$ be the corresponding complete measure space. Prove that $f \in L^1(X, \overline{\mu})$ if and only if there exists $g \in L^1(X, \mu)$ such that $f = g$ $\overline{\mu}$-a.e.

Reverse direction: Since $g \in L^1(X, \mu)$, we know that
$
g \text{ is } \Sigma\text{-measurable and } \int_X |g| \, d\mu < \infty.
$
By assumption, $f = g$ $\overline{\mu}$-a.e., which implies $|f| = |g|$ $\overline{\mu}$-a.e.
Thus, the integral of $|f|$ with respect to $\overline{\mu}$ satisfies
$$
\int_X |f| \, d\overline{\mu} = \int_X |g| \, d\overline{\mu}.
$$
Since $g$ is $\Sigma$-measurable and $\overline{\mu}$ extends $\mu$, we have
$$
\int_X |g| \, d\overline{\mu} = \int_X |g| \, d\mu.
$$
Combining these, we get
$$
\int_X |f| \, d\overline{\mu} = \int_X |g| \, d\mu < \infty,
$$
where the inequality follows from the fact that $g \in L^1(X, \mu)$.
Hence, $f \in L^1(X, \overline{\mu})$.
Can you check this? For the forward direction, I don't know where to start. How do I construct the function $g$?

You can prove this on indicator functions, where it's pretty much the definition of the completed measure. The same idea gives you the property for simple functions, and by taking a limit you get the same for all $L^1$-functions.

I face the same problem. If $f=\chi_A$, what should be $g$? Is it $\chi_B$ where $B$ union a null set equals $A$?

Exactly, and then you take the countable combinations, and then the limits

But this works only for the forward direction, right?

Yes, the other direction seems fine
